# Lubuntu: After log in hangs. Need to backup and save my files

Tags: lubuntu, login, backup

Problem: My lubuntu was having some problems with firefox yesterday so I decided to close it down and restart. But after logging in it just hangs. Nothing happens.

Afters some searching on here I tried to update via terminal, but still no help.

I can log in as a guest and I can log in via terminal but I cannot log in as normal and get access to my files. I am a newbie with linux and would like to back up my files and then just install something new.

So how can i back up my data while not being able to log in?

Assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Enter Virtual Terminal (use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> shortcut).
2. Log in to your account.
3. Plug in your pendrive (or if you have another partition for data, just do nothing).
4. Detect the number of your partition. You can get labels of partitions by issuing `sudo blkid` command.
5. Mount your desired partition:

   `mkdir $HOME/rescue && sudo mount /dev/sd[letter of drive][number of parttion] $HOME/rescue`
6. Copy your files:

   `cp -Rv directory $HOME/rescue`

Comment: `cp` with directories would need the `--recursive` option.

Comment: The pen drive is not being recognized?

Answer (score 0):

If you can login as guest you just have a problem with your usersettings. You can revert your usersettings by doing the following.

Log into a terminal under your username and then type the following command (and press enter).

```
cd ~/ && ls -A
```

Now, you need to delete every file listed that begins with a period " . " (like .mozilla and .profile). **This will delete your settings and profiles like your firefox profile** **but will leave your other saved items, software, downloads, documents etc. in tact**. To do this, we will be using the rm command with the recursive option to delete these directories.

Just type `sudo rm -R` followed by a single space followed by typing a list of the filenames you need to delete using only single spaces to seperate each name. You may then press enter after the entire list is done.

example:

```
sudo rm -R .audacity-data .bash_history .bash_logout .bash_profile .bashrc .cache
```

(I've only included 6 files in this example just to give you a rough idea of what you need to do; your list may very well include 30 or 40 files).

**Also, remember and don't forget to include the period when you type each name.

You should be able to log right in but if not, save any unsaved files you might have been working on and reboot.